# LIBGDX runs fine on desktop, but crashes on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been looking through this code for over 2 days and still can't find any errors in the code as to why it crashes on Android. It works perfectly fine on desktop.

Android Target: 4.0.3

Android Phone used: HTC Desire C

Logcat:

---

```
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2955
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.Player.readPlayer(Player.java:191)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.MainMenu.loadPlayer(MainMenu.java:278)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:127)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.GameHub.create(GameHub.java:12)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
04-07 16:42:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1224)
```

---

Like I said, this works fine on desktop, but crashes on Android.

### Player class

```
package com.survivegameandroidtest.survive;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

SpriteBatch batch;
static Vector2 position = new Vector2(1,1);

Vector2 size;

Vector2 boundSize;

Vector2 boundOffset;
Texture texture;
Rectangle bounds;
String direction = "";
StringCheese cheese;
EnemyCheddarling enemy;

int health = 0, damage;
boolean alive;

private static final int col = 4, row = 4;
Animation animation;
TextureRegion[] frames;
TextureRegion currentFrame;
float stateTime;

int speed = 0;

static String name = "";

public Player(Texture texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 size, Vector2 boundSize,     Vector2 boundOffset) {
    this.texture = texture;
    Player.position = position;
    this.size = size;
    this.boundOffset = boundOffset;

    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(texture, texture.getWidth() /     col, texture.getHeight() / row);
    frames = new TextureRegion[col * row];

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            frames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }

    animation = new Animation(1f, frames);
    stateTime = 0f;
    currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0);

    this.boundSize = boundSize;
    bounds = new Rectangle(position.x + boundOffset.x, position.y +     boundOffset.y, boundSize.x, boundSize.y);

    health = 100;
    damage = 20;
    alive = true;

    name = "SET YO NAME FOOL";
}

public void update() {
    bounds.set(position.x + boundOffset.x, position.y + boundOffset.y,     boundSize.x, boundSize.y);

    if(health <= 0) {
        alive = false;
    }

    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*8;
    if(stateTime > col) {
        stateTime = 0;
    }

    //WASD MOVE METHOD
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
        position.y += 2f;
        currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(12 + stateTime);
        direction = "up";
        speed = 2;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
        position.x -= 2f;
        currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(4 + stateTime);
        direction = "left";
        speed = 2;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
        position.y -= 2f;
        currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0 + stateTime);
        direction = "down";
        speed = 2;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
        position.x += 2f;
        currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(8 + stateTime);
        direction = "right";
        speed = 2;
    }

    //ACCELEROMETER MOVE METHOD
    if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() != 1 || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() != 0     || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() != -1 || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() != 1 ||     Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() != 0 || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() != -1) {
        for(int rotation = 2; rotation < 5; rotation++) {
            if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() <= -rotation) { //DOWN
                position.y += rotation;
                currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(12 +     stateTime);
                direction = "down";
                speed = rotation;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() >= rotation) { //UP
                position.y -= rotation;
                currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0 + stateTime);
                direction = "up";
                speed = rotation;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() <= -rotation) { //LEFT
                position.x -= rotation;
                currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(4 + stateTime);
                direction = "left";
                speed = rotation;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() >= rotation) { //RIGHT
                position.x += rotation;
                currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(8 + stateTime);
                direction = "right";
                speed = rotation;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(currentFrame, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
}

public void collision() {
    if(direction == "up") {
        position.y += speed;
    }
    if(direction == "down") {
        position.y -= speed;
    }
    if(direction == "left") {
        position.y -= speed;
    }
    if(direction == "right") {
        position.y += speed;
    }
}

public static void savePlayer(Player playerName) throws IOException{
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("player.dat");
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        file.writeBytes(serialize(name), false);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }finally{
        if(out != null) try{out.close();} catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("Saving Player" + "  " +     deserialize(file.readBytes()));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String readPlayer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String playerName = "";
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("player.dat");
    playerName = (String) deserialize(file.readBytes());
    System.out.println("Reading Player");
    return playerName;
}

private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException,     ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
    return o.readObject();
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS

public SpriteBatch getBatch() {
    return batch;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String object) {
    Player.name = object;
}

public Vector2 getBoundOffset() {
    return boundOffset;
}

public void setBoundOffset(Vector2 boundOffset) {
    this.boundOffset = boundOffset;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

public boolean isAlive() {
    return alive;
}

public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
    this.alive = alive;
}

public String getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(String direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public StringCheese getCheese() {
    return cheese;
}

public void setCheese(StringCheese cheese) {
    this.cheese = cheese;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}

public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
    this.bounds = bounds;
}

public Vector2 getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(Vector2 size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public Vector2 getBoundSize() {
    return boundSize;
}

public void setBoundSize(Vector2 boundSize) {
    this.boundSize = boundSize;
}

public Texture getTexture() {
    return texture;
}

public void setTexture(Texture texture) {
    this.texture = texture;
}

public Animation getAnimation() {
    return animation;
}

public void setAnimation(Animation animation) {
    this.animation = animation;
}

public TextureRegion[] getFrames() {
    return frames;
}

public void setFrames(TextureRegion[] frames) {
    this.frames = frames;
}

public TextureRegion getCurrentFrame() {
    return currentFrame;
}

public void setCurrentFrame(TextureRegion currentFrame) {
    this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
}

public float getStateTime() {
    return stateTime;
}

public void setStateTime(float stateTime) {
    this.stateTime = stateTime;
}

public static int getCol() {
    return col;
}

public static int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public void setBatch(SpriteBatch batch) {
    this.batch = batch;
}

public Vector2 getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
    Player.position = position;
}

}
```

---

In savePlayer(), I try to serialize the String variable 'name'.

System.out.println("Saving Player" + "  " + deserialize(file.readBytes()));

^ This line of code prints out "Saving Player  Hosif Yimms" in the console, and none of the methods return a Vector2.

---

**ANSWER:** Used a FileHandle method to save the players name, as deserialize return an Object, not String.

Comment: deserialize() can potentially return *any* subclass of Object.  Likely your output data isn't what you think it is, or has been corrupted.

Comment: Why are you using Object serialization for strings anyway? Just get a reader/writer for your FileHandle.

Comment: Thanks guys! The problem's solved.

Comment: Please add an answer then and mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using Object serialization for strings anyway? Just get a reader/writer for your FileHandle. –  Chase

```
public static void savePlayerName(Player player) {
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("playername.dat");
    file.writeString(player.getName(), false);
}

public static String readPlayerName() {
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("playername.dat");
    String name = file.readString();
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Answering "why are you..." and then suggesting using something else completely different without addressing the actual BUG he is experiencing doesnt address the issue OR explain why you think he should use a different approach.